# Ajax calls getting incremented every time after the content is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m loading some content using ajax call, Inside that contents there are some hyperlinks which when user clicks it loads the content in the same div the problem is when the user clicks the back botton(another ajax call) the content of the div is repalced with the old content(having hyperlinks) ,now when u again click the Hyperlink its functions smoothly but its goes to the action twice, and this phenomenon keeps on increasing the no of time u press the back button and click on some Hyperlink.

Please anyone help me know what exactly happening to the process which is causing increment in action call every time the user clicks it

**UPDATE**

```
$(document).on("click",".selector",function(){
var link=($(this).parent().find("td a").attr("href"));
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    async : true,
    url : link,
    statusCode : {
        404 : function() {
            alert("Error in Application");
        }
    },
    cache : false,
    success : function(data) {
        alert(data);
        $('#load').html('');
        $('#load').html(data);
    }
});
  });
```

Comment: It seems like you're binding delegated event listeners at each callback. But we cannot help you identify the problem in your code unless you show it to us.

Comment: ok the problem is binding related it has nothing to do with the 'cache' @DavidHedlund

Comment: Can you post the code which binds the event handlers to the hyperlinks, if any?

Comment: @all i have updated my code for js

Comment: What does the back button code look like?

Comment: It sounds like the event binding is getting added repeatedly to the anchor tags.  It's tough to debug without a bit more code, but perhaps stopping the anchor tag browser actions (via preventDefault()) might help...

Answer (score -1):

Try with Call `event.stopPropagation();` after successfull ajax request